# Create an iMessage Extension without storyboards?

Tags: ios, swift, imessage-extension

I am wondering if it is possible (and if so, some elaboration and steps to achieve) building out a custom iMessage
Extension WITHOUT using storyboards? I have my core app, and then have the additional iMessage extension target. My main app is working fine without storyboards.

I followed the tutorial [here](https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2016/12/14/how-to-create-imessage-app-extension-without-storyboard/), however it is not working and makes the original app look really funky upon deleting the `Launch screen interface file base name` info.plist entry from the main app. This tutorial is from 2016 and uses Objective C, so that might also have something to do with it.

I know that the launch screen for the main app now requires a storyboard, and everything is working fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to do it in SwiftUI.

Here's a link to another question that has a complete example of a bug, but to your question has a stub of a message extension that displays a very simple view.  You could expand on that.

[imessage extension app group conversation send fails on first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400098/imessage-extension-app-group-conversation-send-fails-on-first-run)